# Django : Form data not saving

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-1.10

I have a `form` where user just uploads an image,but problem is when I choose an image and press button to submit. It says `This field is required.`on the page although I have already pointed the image. And that's all it does.I checked if it was actually submitted but no, it was not.What could be the problem ?

**Models.py**

```
class pic(models.Model):
    username = "anonymous"
    picpost = models.ImageField(upload_to='anon_pics')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import pic

class PicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = pic
        fields = [
            "picpost"
        ]
```

**view.py**

```
def pic_create(request):
    form = PicForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False) 
        instance.save()
    context = {
        "form" : form,
    }
    return render(request, "create_pic.html", context)
```

**create_pic.html**

```
<body>
    <form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type='submit' value='Upload Picture' />
    </form>
</body>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here.

Firstly, your view needs to pass `request.FILES` as well as `request.POST` to the form.

Secondly,  your form element in the template needs to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! `form = PicForm(request.POST,request.FILES or None)` right?